# Java - Best way to grab ALL Strings between two Strings? (regex?)

Tags: java, regex, string

This question has been bugging me for a long time now but essentially I'm looking for the most efficient way to grab all Strings between two Strings.

The way I have been doing it for many months now is through using a bunch of temporary indices, strings, substrings, and it's really messy. (Why does Java not have a native method such as `String substring(String start, String end)`?

Say I have a String:

`abcabc [pattern1]foo[pattern2] abcdefg [pattern1]bar[pattern2] morestuff`

The end goal would be to output `foo` and `bar`. (And later to be added into a JList)

I've been trying to incorporate regex in `.split()` but haven't been successful. I've tried syntax using `*`'s and `.`'s but I don't think it's quite what my intention is especially since `.split()` only takes one argument to split against.

Otherwise I think another way is to use the Pattern and Matcher classes? But I'm really fuzzy on the appropriate procedure.

Comment: You definitely want to use a `Matcher` for this.

Comment: @Amber "definitely"?? That's pretty strong language considering what's possible in code. See my one-liner answer (that *doesn't* use a `matcher`!)

Comment: @Bohemian And see my *comment* on your answer. Just because you *can* use something doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can construct the regex to do this for you:

```
// pattern1 and pattern2 are String objects
String regexString = Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2);
```

This will treat the `pattern1` and `pattern2` as **literal** text, and the text in between the patterns is captured in the first [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg). You can remove [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) if you want to use regex, but I **don't** guarantee anything if you do that.

You can add some customization of how the match should occurs by adding flags to the `regexString`.

- If you want Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching, then add `(?iu)` at the beginning of `regexString`, or supply `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` flag to [`Pattern.compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String,%20int)) method.
- If you want to capture the content even if the two delimiting strings appear across lines, then add `(?s)` before `(.*?)`, i.e. `"(?s)(.*?)"`, or supply [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to [`Pattern.compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String,%20int)) method.

Then compile the regex, obtain a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object, iterate through the matches and save them into a `List` (or any `Collection`, it's up to you).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
// text contains the full text that you want to extract data
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
  String textInBetween = matcher.group(1); // Since (.*?) is capturing group 1
  // You can insert match into a List/Collection here
}
```

Testing code:

```
String pattern1 = "hgb";
String pattern2 = "|";
String text = "sdfjsdkhfkjsdf hgb sdjfkhsdkfsdf |sdfjksdhfjksd sdf sdkjfhsdkf | sdkjfh hgb sdkjfdshfks|";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Do note that if you search for the text between `foo` and `bar` in this input `foo text foo text bar text bar` with the method above, you will get one match, which is  `text foo text` .

Comment: Thank you! :) This works great! Just one thing, the part `String textInBetween = m.group(1); // Since (.*?) is capturing group 1 ` should probably be `matcher.group(1)` but that's a minor typo and the testing code works brilliantly!

Comment: @Justin: Thanks for spotting the typo. I copy and paste, but failed to edit everything.

Comment: This doesn't work when new line character is between our starting and ending words.

Comment: @Tajchert: Just change the part `(.*?)` to `(?s)(.*?)`, or add `Pattern.DOTALL` flag into `Pattern.compile`.

Comment: Beautiful clean solution - thank you all for solving this problem for us all. To all, please make sure you add Pattern.DOITALL so you can capture multiline text between your patterns.

Comment: @Prashanth Thanks alot! I was trying out the code but it wasn't working for multi-line. Your flag helped me!

Answer (score 13):

Here's a one-liner that does it all:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList( input.replaceAll("^.*?pattern1", "")
    .split("pattern2.*?(pattern1|$)"));
```

The breakdown is:

1. Remove everything up to pattern1 (required to not end up with an empty string as the first term)
2. Split on input (non-greedy `.*?`) between pattern2 and pattern1 (or end of input)
3. Use the utility method `Arrays.asList()` to generate a `List<String>`

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = "abcabc pattern1foopattern2 abcdefg pattern1barpattern2 morestuff";
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList( input.replaceAll("^.*?pattern1", "").split("pattern2.*?(pattern1|$)"));
    System.out.println( strings);
}
```

Output:

```
[foo, bar]
```

Comment: And is also extremely difficult to follow. I would not want to see this in code I had to maintain.

Comment: Really? I coded this in a jiffy. Anyway, just add my explanation as in-code comments and everybody would be happy

Comment: Or you could do it using a Matcher, not have to use comments to explain what's going on, and better support potential future changes to the requirements - for instance, your solution breaks down if it becomes desirable to match, said, multiple different pairs of start/end markers. Using a matcher also doesn't require constructing an intermediate string, which could have a significant performance aspect if the strings being operated on are large.

Comment: Spiffy one-liner! I'm going to try to get more rep and come back to mark this as useful!

Comment: @Justin Thanks. I live my the mantra "less code is good" (with the caveat that it remains readable) - it keeps the "signal to noise ratio" of your code high. I would happily use this code in production. It's easy to understand if you know regex well, and it uses the API to do all the heavy lifting for you. I can't understand why people voted the other answer over this one - it has heaps of code and does nothing more than this one line, and having heaps of code makes it ***less*** readable!

Comment: @Bohemian, do you have some solution when pattern1 and pattern2 matching should be done with ignore case?

Comment: @ddmytrenko sure, just add the "ignore case" flag  `(?i)` to the regexes: `List<String> strings = Arrays.asList( input.replaceAll("^.*?(?i)pattern1", "")
    .split("(?i)pattern2.*?(pattern1|$)"));`

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
String str = "its a string with pattern1 aleatory pattern2 things between pattern1 and pattern2 and sometimes pattern1 pattern2 nothing";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
                            Pattern.quote("pattern1")
                            + "(.*?)"
                            + Pattern.quote("pattern2")
                   ).matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
    String match = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(">"+match+"<");
    //here you insert 'match' into the list
}
```

It prints:

```
> aleatory <
> and <
> <
```

Comment: What if I want pattern 1 and pattern 2 to be included in the output?

Comment: @R11G you can simply concat the pattern variables in the output, or move the parenthesis to include the patterns: `"("+ Pattern.quote(pat1) + ".*?" + Pattern.quote(pat2) + ")"` and grab it by `m.group(1)`.