# Split a String Using Java Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

```
<189>131: *Jan  2 13:20:47.581: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to up
```

From the above String, I want to split the the following:

```
 189  -between <>
    Jan  2 13:20:47.581  -between * %
    LINEPROTO 
    5
    UPDOWN
    FastEthernet0/1 - after string Interface
    up  -after String state to status
```

Final String array will be:

```
[189],[Jan  2 13:20:47.581],[LINEPROTO],[5],[UPDOWN],[FastEthernet0/1],[up]
```

How do I do this using java regex?

Comment: Do you understand how to use regex in the first place?

Comment: First of all did you try using regex?..Any error that you came across while using it?

Comment: i tried withhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255353/java-best-way-to-grab-all-strings-between-two-strings-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will capture the groups that you required:

```
<(.+)>.+?[*](.+?)%(LINEPROTO)-(.+?)-(.+?):.+?Interface (.+?), changed state to (.+)
```

The groups are (separated by commas):

189,Jan  2 13:20:47.581:,LINEPROTO,5,UPDOWN,FastEthernet0/1,up

Note that `Jan  2 13:20:47.581:` includes the ':' since you indicated that you wanted everything between * and %.

Explanation of the regex:

- () are groups.
- +? is non-greedy
- `[*]` is the '*' character rather than the regex operator.

Also, I assume that you didn't want the literal 'LINEPROTO' (even though your instructions seemed to indicate you do). In which case you will want:

```
<(.+)>.+?[*](.+?)%(.+)-(.+?)-(.+?):.+?Interface (.+?), changed state to (.+)
```

**Update based on comment**

Updated regex is:

```
<(.+)>.+?[*](.+?): %(.+)-(.+?)-(.+?):.+?Interface (.+?), changed state to (.+)
```

Groups will be:
189, Jan  2 13:20:47.581, LINEPROTO, 5, UPDOWN, FastEthernet0/1, up

Comment: Thanks for the reply i want first array element as 189 instead of 9 and Jan 2 13:20:47.581 instead of Jan 2 13:20:47.581:

Comment: @user2413387 - I have updated to satisfy this - see the last regex.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to look into JavaScript's [substr](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_substr.htm) or [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)..Should help you out.