# Java - How to parse information out of HTML Site?

Tags: java, html, parsing, servlets

I have a StringBuffer with a HTML Site in it and want to have some specific information of this Site.

1 line is f.e.:

> img class="a" data-src="http://test.com" src="" /<

and i want a String with "http://test.com".

Is there a function/parser which can help me?

Comment: jsoup (http://jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question and you could've found the answer with a quick Google search.

Look into Regular Expression (regex) as you'll need it probably more than once.

Comment: jeah but i didnt found what i need. I need a regex lik that:

xxxINEEDTHATyyy

where i can say: i want "INEEDTHAT" between xxx and yyy
where INEEDTHAT is unknown

Comment: I don't want to take credit for someone else's answer, so here's a link to the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255353/java-best-way-to-grab-all-strings-between-two-strings-regex

Comment: thx that is perfect. one last question: now i have 2 patterns (p,l), and i what them in the same matcher(m) because of the order:

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + > > Pattern.quote(pattern2));
Pattern l = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern3) + "(.*?)" + > > Pattern.quote(pattern4));
Matcher m = p.matcher(res.toString());
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
     }

How do i get both patterns in m?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup will do the trick, just do a little css and you can get whatever element you need.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.com").get();
//DOM Selector CSS String see jsoup docs.
//This will select all image elements with the a class similar to css. IE: img.a
//http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
//Get all elements that are images with class of a
```

`Elements images = doc.select("img.a");`

```
for (Element image : images) {
//Get the url of the image
```

`String url = image.attr("data-src");;`

`}`

Comment: i didnt get it.

i load the html page in doc, but what does
doc.select("img[data-src]"); do?
i dont know the data-src and dont want the src of all images, only the images with the class a

Comment: @user3688653 updated this for clarity let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) framework.

There is ["Selector"](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) mechanism to find and operate with html elements.